# Setting Cookies from incoming request to outbound fetch() call in NextJS via Relay

Tags: next.js, relayjs

I'm using the latest version of NextJS (the one with App router) and integrating it with React-Relay. I have to pass in the `Cookie` that I get from the browser to the outbound request to my api server.

From what I understand, in App router, I can access `cookie` from `next/header` but since I need to use it in the function that needs to be provided to `RelayEnvironment`, I cannot access this server only function in the code path that's shared with the Client component as well since `RelayEnvironmentProvider` uses `React.Context` and takes in `environment` as a prop.

Basically, `layout.ts` sets up `RelayEnvironmentProvider` -> `environment` sets up the network -> network uses `fetch()` and that's where I need to pass in the `cookie` header

I tried adding a middleware, reading the cookie from request and setting it up in the `process.env` (not nice, but I exhausted all other options I could think of) but this approach for some reason, doesn't provide the same envs to the `fetch()` call site